# NoSuchMethodError: 'void setActiveProfiles(java.lang.String)' Spring Boot Starter Installation in eclipse went wrong

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, maven, nosuchmethoderror, spring-boot-starter

I am trying to use Spring Boot Starter in Eclipse and after Creating a new SpringBoot project I receive the following message:

> NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.ResolverConfiguration.setActiveProfiles(java.lang.String)'

I tried to deinstall m2e package in Preferances -> Help -> Install/Update, but that doesn't help. Does one know other ways to get the solution.

Comment: Which versions of M2E and the Spring tools are involved? NoSuchMethodError means you have versions mixed together that either weren't intended to be.

Comment: M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse version: 2.3.0.20230523-2033 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 
Spring tools 4.3.23.20190313-CI

Comment: Your Spring Tools are very much out of date. They're up to 4.19 at this point, and if the qualifier in that version is correct, you have a build from 2019.